# Recomendaciones para arquitectura de cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Hola amigos estoy recolectando opiniones y sugerencias con respecto a la como armar mi cloud. Les comento que tengo que alojar y como lo tengo pensado.

Los proyectos que tengo son un sistema en la nube que son dos proyectos separados una API en nodejs con MongoDB y el front con Angular en un apache

Luego tengo que alojar 3 e commerce que consultarian la API que nombre antes.

Luego tengo una web normal estática.

Luego hay otra web que es toda la documentación del primer proyecto.

Podría meter todo en un solo vps tranquilamente pero es recomendable ? Cuántas web se sugiere alojar en un vps ? La API la separó a un vps aparte y luego cada front a otro vps ?

Tengan en cuenta que uso Google plataform.

Saludos
Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para GCP, depende del enfoque que tengas, te propondré dos soluciones, todo depende de la capacidad que requieras para tus servicios, que tanto tráfico tienes, y que tantos procesos realices.

1 CostEfective ( Enfocada en minimizar costos sin perder capacidad )

- Para todos los sitios estáticos puedes utilizar Cloud Storage (
  Bucket ) , el cual te permite sin problema alojar sitios estáticos,
  incluso el front podrías alojarlo ahí, pero esto último no es 100%
  recomendable.

  - Debido a que tu aplicación Front está en Angular, podrías optar por desplegarla en Google App Engine Flex (GAE Flex), comenzando
    desde los requerimientos mínimos y escalandolos de ser necesario.
  - En el caso de tu API NodeJS, considera migrar a Cloud Functions, este es un servicio Serveless que te permite alojar microservicios
    basados en Node JS, te ofrece autenticación y dominio, y solo gastas
    al utilizarlo. O puedes dejarlo en un GAE Flex igual.
- Sinembargo en GCP no existe como tal Mongo Db en Cloud, como fuera el caso de Azure y su ( Cosmos ), tienes la opción de migrar a otra
  clase de NoSQL, como DataStore,o alojar la base en un Compute Engine,
  a su vez, en caso de ser así podrías dejar la APÏ en este mismo grupo
  de instancias.

  - Para el caso de los ecommerce, todo depende de su desarrollo, en pincipio, cada front y back deberían encontrarse separados, sí tu
    ecommerce se encuentra en uno de los siguientes lenguajes : Java, Go,
    Python, PHP lo puedes desplegar sin problemas en GAE; en caso de no
    ser así podrías utilizar GAE Flex.
- Para la configuración de tus VPC, en principio para comunicarse entre back y front deben de encontrarse en una VPC PRIVADA, y a su
  vez en dos VPC más configuradas en distintas interfaces, una para
  FRONT y otra para BACK, la única que tendría salida al público sería
  la de Front, no olvides configurar las reglas de firewall.

2 High Availability ( Alta disponibilidad )

- Cloud Storage para estáticos, GAE Flex para Front
- APÏ desplegada en Kubernetes, utlizando 2 pods inicialmente, y permitiendo el autoescalamiento con un Balanceador de Carga interno para la conexión posterior con los ecommerce.
- Como mencioné antes GCP no tiene como tal Mongo DB en cloud, puedes alojar la base en un grupo de instancias Compute Engine o deplegarla en Kubernetes, en mi experiencia aunque Kubernetes es la sugerencia por disponibilidad, es más fácil que una mayor cantidad de personas la comprendan en Compute Engine.
- Cómo dije antes, el front y el back de los ecommerce debería estar separado, pero si requieres mayor acceso al file system, o un sistema operativo personalizado, los podrías alojar en un grupo de instancias -> Compute Engine. Configurados con autoescalamiento en Base a un Balanceador HTTP/HTTPS
- La configuración de los balanceadores dentro de tu VPC es de suma importancia para alta disponibilidad, de igual manera la red fronnt y back deberia encontrarse separada, en caso de que los ecommerce completos los alojarás en un grupo de instancias, de igual manera de recomiendo tenerlas separdas, el acceso a la base, en caso de estar en instancia separadas, deberas hacerlo por un Bastion Host, que de salida a las consultas o conexiones de las APIs

Espero te haya podido Ayudar :)

En caso de no estar familiarizado con los términos te dejo un pequeño glosario.

- GAE: Google App Engine
- Compute Engine: Virtual Machine en GCP
- VPC: Virtual Private Cloud
- Cloud Storage: Alamacenamiento de objetos/blob, basado en arquitectura bucket
- DataStore: Base de Datos NoSQL Document Base, propia de GCP
- Kubernetes: Framework para orquestamiento de contenedores Docker

Comment: Antes que nada muchas gracias se me ocurre basado en lo que me comentas. Mi base de datos que es mongo alojarla en mongo atlas. Mi API hacer un solo compute engine osea un vps y alojarla ahi (aca estaria toda la lógica de mi negocio ). El resto de los proyectos hacer por cada proyecto un app engine. Lo que me queda la duda como resuelvo el tema del DNS por que tengo 4 dominios y de uno de esos 4 tengo 25 subdominios. Ademas tengo la suite de google con el correo. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias Aprendiz, lo leo, @FrancoAndroetto, en el caso de tu DNS puedes administrarlo con Cloud DNS, es una forma de acceder a diferentes recursos publicados por medio de un DNS.